# How to set modified file's metadata to equal the created_on value of recovered images?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, file-metadata

I recovered images from an android `LOST.DIR` folder.

The data recovered successfully, now I'd like to set the `modified` timestamp of the file to be equal to the `created on` value of the binary data.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10

[image]

[image]

In this case, I'd like both `modified` and `created on` to equal `2019:06:03`, the format doesn't matter.

The solution should support looping over all files in the folder.

Comment: AFAIK not tools exist for that. Also see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591384/copying-or-restoring-crtime-for-files-directories-on-ext4fs-filesystem

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov: I understand the OP want to set the file system *modified* timestand to be equal to the EXIF *creation time*. The link you posted is about setting the *creation* time in the file system.

Comment: The file modified timestamp is copied and respected by most file utilities under the Sun and created on time is a whole different affair which is what the OP is seemingly looking for.

Comment: The recovery process the OP ran created new files with create and modified timestamps equal to the revocery time, right? I understand the OP would like the files system modified timestamp the reclect the creation time of the original image file (which is an EXIF tag).

Comment: Actually now I suspect that the recovery didn't work. Because the files doesn't have the file type suffix. But I am able to see the file type in the properties popup and to open the file in image viewer. If I add the suffix manually, I can even open it on my mobile. I tried using `photorec`.

Comment: You can open the files recovered in an image viewer and it looks like the images you expect? So the recovery did succeed, I'd say. The suffix in the file name is just part of the filename, and is interpreted by some programs. It has no influence on the content of the files. You might name a *pure text file* "image.jpg", but that doesn't make an image out of it. Rename the files and add the suffix (jpg, tif, or whatever applies).

Comment: Ok, than the recovery did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an *EXIF tool* to retrieve the image creation timestamp, then use `touch` to set the filesystem timestamp accordingly.

I just tried this shell script (e.g. *ex.sh*) under ArchLinux where I installed *perl-image-exiftool*

```
#! /bin/bash

for fn; do
    ls -l "$fn"
    touch -m -t "$(exiftool -createdate -d '%Y%m%d%H%M.%S' -s3 "$fn")" "$fn"
    ls -l "$fn"
    echo "------------------"
done
```

You can omit the *echo* and *ls...* lines; they're just there to display before and after timestamps of the files.

```
./ex.sh *.jpg
```

or

```
./ex.sh 01.jpg 02.jpg
```

Comment: @Freddy: Thanks. Acutally the lowercase "s" was a typo I didn't recognize :-(

Comment: I made a small edit, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not if you help me to understand what the benefit of *"$fn"* over *$fn* is :-) I understand single quoting the parameter of the *-d* option is to avoid indvertant changes by the shell. But why to quote the shell variables which I want to be exnaded before the line is executed.

Comment: There is no difference if your filenames don't contain any whitespace characters :)
See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694).

Comment: The single quotes around the format string are not strictly necessary in this example as there is no whitespace in the format string. Same goes for the quotes
of the command substitution `"$(...)"`. But it's safer to quote them anyway.
The quotes around `$fn` prevents [splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) on the values of the `IFS` variable (space, tab, newline).