# File timestamps on different OSes

Tags: filesystems, ext4, timestamps, ntfs

Are file timestamps (Created/birth, accessed and modified) the same on different OSes? Particularly on Windows and Linux.

I downloaded a file which is modified on Windows and its timestamps looked right on my Linux system with ext4.

- Let's say I modified a file on a NTFS filesystem mounted on Linux.
- Or I copied it to my ext4 partition, modified it (or accessed it) and put it back (for modified and/or accessed).
- Or I created a file on ext4 and put it to a NTFS partition (for birth).

Will they look right on Windows?

I use Windows and Linux together and I want to keep timestamps same.

Comment: ext4 does not store creation time.

Comment: ctime is traditionally the last change time, not creation time. various filesystems may or may not have extensions to also store the birth time

Comment: @jordanm it does, but [it has been made accessible only fairly recently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407305/70524).

Comment: ext4 **does store** creation time and has always done.

Comment: MTP rsync --help, might help, might not.

Answer (score 1):

Linux utilities, aside from `star`, cannot copy the birth/creation time but `star` does that only for files extracted/restored from `.tar` archives, so basically we have none.

Please refer to this question for more info: [Copying or restoring crtime for files/directories on ext4fs filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591384/copying-or-restoring-crtime-for-files-directories-on-ext4fs-filesystem)